# How to set up Web.Config transformation to cater for Local and production configurations?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have this dilemma of having to have different connection strings for the web.config on my local machine and to have a release transformation that would make the production binaries use the machine.config on the web server.

So I have these files in my Visual Studio solution:

`Web.Config`
`Web.Debug.Config`
`Web.Release.Config`

In the web.config I have removed and added new connection strings.

```
<remove name="connstring">
<add name="connstring" ConnectionString="blahblah" />
```

What I want to do is to have nothing in final web.config when deployed (by TFS build) to the web server so that my web application would use anything in the machine.config on the server.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove configuration settings with the RemoveAll transform attribute. Assuming you are deploying the Release build configuration, you can generate a completely empty web.config by putting the following in Web.Release.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" />
```

This resulting web.config will have the XML declaration at the top and nothing else.

If you only want to remove certain configuration sub-sections, add the RemoveAll transform attribute to the section you want removed. For example, the following Web.Release.Config will remove all application settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <appSettings xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" />
</configuration>
```

See the full [Transformation Syntax Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.